# Lightning component focus on lightning:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inputfield, lightning-inputfield

I have a `<lightning:inputField aura:id="inputField1">` in a modal window, and I want to focus on this field when the modal opens, so that the user doesn't have to use their mouse or tab to set focus.

However, when I try to set focus like this: `cmp.find("inputField1").focus()`, it throws an error saying that `focus() is not a function.` This does work, however, with `lightning:input aura:id="inputField1"`.

I assume this is how Salesforce is using the Locker (or Proxy) to create elements, and it's not giving me a reference to the actual input element (maybe for security concerns in Communities or Portals).

Can anyone think of a way to set focus on this field?

Comment: are there 2 components in your app with same id="inputField" ?

Comment: also can you check whats the value of `console.log(Array.isArray(cmp.find("inputField")));`

Comment: No, it's a singular element, the id is not actually "inputField" but descriptive of the application. The isArray function therefore returns false.

Comment: can you add some more code that will help us reproduce this issue?

Comment: No, but I think it's pretty descriptive. If you add a <lightning:inputField> element and then in your javascript controller try to call, cmp.find("you_element").focus(), you will get an error (or so I believe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**lightning:inputField**  does not support focus as per their official documentation.

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification

Comment: You used <lightning:input>, not <lightning:inputField>, which I'm assuming gets generated different from the Lightning perspective. As in my question, <lightning:input> seems to work fine.

Comment: Mybad, I got confused between the two.

Comment: Ah yeah I see the documentation for input:field lists the function as supported. Nice find.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not supported in aura lightning:inputField, but it is now supported in the LWC lightning-input-field component:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293343/unable-to-set-focus-on-lightning-input-field-in-lwc/374356#374356

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the issue is the following:

Add this class to the component CSS file:

```
.THIS .custom_focus input  {
outline: 0;
border-color: rgb(21, 137, 238);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0070d2;}
```

Define a boolean attribute for every Lightning:inputField on the form:

```
<aura:attribute name="isFocus1" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="isFocus2" type="Boolean" default="false" />
```

Apply conditional styling to every lightning:inputField on the recordEditForm and wrap them with 'onclick' sensitive div-s:

```
<div onclick="{!c.onClick}"><lightning:inputField fieldName="FieldName1" class="{! v.isFocus1 ? 'custom_focus' : ''}" type="Lookup" /></div>
<div onclick="{!c.onClick}"><lightning:inputField fieldName="FieldName2" class="{! v.isFocus2 ? 'custom_focus' : ''}" type="Picklist"/></div>
```

Implement controller logic to apply 'focus' class to some specific lightning:inputField and to remove the focus from all the inputs when any gets clicked:

```
focusOnSmth: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.isFocus1', true);
},

onClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.isFocus1', false);
    cmp.set('v.isFocus2', false);
},
```

That did the trick for me. Cheers