# Unable to set focus on lightning-input-field in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am using lightning-record-edit-form to display to users custom Opportunity form with the help of lightning-input-field. However, I am unable to set focus on a particular field.

I have a  in a modal window, and I want to focus on this field when the modal opens so that the user doesn't have to use their mouse or tab to set focus.

However, when I try to set focus on Amount field using the below code, it didn't work.

```
  let fieldToFocus = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input-field[data-fieldname='Amount']");
    if(fieldToFocus){
        fieldToFocus.focus();
    }
```

Has anybody been able to make focus work with lightning-input-field?

Comment: The lightning-input-field does not support the focus method.
You can find all the supported method here in the "Methods" section - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification

Workaround - you need to use the css for doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately **lightning-input-field** doesn't have @api method **focus**.
You can use **[lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification)** instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Recent Updates:

Salesforce seems to have recently updated the global methods for lightning-input-field and snuck in a focus method, alongside the reset method that's been there:
[Input Field Specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification)

[image: Updated Methods for lightning-input-field includes focus.]

## Sample code

### component.html

```
<lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        record-id={recordId}>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Amount" data-fieldname="Amount"></lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

### component.js

Be sure to fire the focus() method when all rendering is completed, or asynchronously (setTimeout method with no delay) to ensure there are no errors on the method call.

```
let elem = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input-field[data-fieldname='Amount']");
setTimeout(() => elem.focus());
```

#### Note:

The focus() method does not work currently in the LWC Local Web Development Server.  You'll need to deploy your code to an org to verify.